# Check if stored proc exists in ADO.Net?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

How do I check that a stored procedure exists using ADO.Net? Is there a specific way to do this (apart from executing SELECT OBJECT_ID() and checking the result)?

Comment: I am guessing the only way to find out is by querying SysObjects, but out of curiosity, could you please explain why you need to do the check? Are you planning on creating an sproc if it does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views like so:

```
Select *
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
Where ROUTINE_NAME = '<your procedure name>'
```

Comment: Is there a predefined method in ADO.Net to do this?

Comment: @HeavyWire - No there is no built-in method to ADO.NET to determine the existence of a stored procedure. You must build a query that you call against SQL Server to determine if a procedure exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether or not there's a way to check without using *any SQL at all*, then the answer is no.

You could use [SQL Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) if you really want a code-only solution, but that's a pretty heavy dependency to add simply to check for the existence of a stored procedure - and it's just going to issue SQL behind the scenes anyway.

It's best if you simply use a `SqlCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't care about adhering to SQL standard constructs (INFORMATION_SCHEMA), you can use the built-in SQL Server system catalog view (2005 and up) to check:

```
SELECT object_id, name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE name = 'your-procedure-name-here'
```